# Classdefnotfound exception thrown in Android app for BaseDexClassLoader

Tags: java, android, eclipse, amazon-web-services

I'm getting a 'classdefnotfound' exception when trying to instantiate AmazonSimpleDBClient because the class 'BaseDexClassLoader' is not found.

I checked my Java Build Path (order and export tab in eclipse) and I have the following checked. Any ideas?

1. Android 4.1.2
2. Android Dependencies
3. Android Private Libraries

Android 4.1.2 has android.jar (16), which should contain this class, right?

Answer (score 0):

AmazonSimpleDBClient  is part of AWS sdk and is not part of standard Android. You need to explicitly include it in your project.

Comment: It is included in my path